# Do 50% of the schoolchildren in Turkey have Kurdish ethnicity?

Tags: children, turkey, demographics, kurds

Michael Gfoeller [claims](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up0VaVN1gxI) in a video that despite only 20% of the present population of Turkey being Kurds, 50% of the school children in Turkey are Kurds, and that consequently:

> Within a generation, Turkey will be pretty much evenly divided between largely secular Kurds and a Turkish population [...]. And so it's going to be a deeply divided society in which half the population will not speak Turkish as its native language.

Is this true? Do 50% of the schoolchildren in Turkey have Kurdish ethnicity?

Comment: There is a secondary claim in the quote, that the Kurds are 'secular'. Since Turkey is officially a secular country with no official religion, the use of this adjective implies that the statement is "loaded". Another problem with the claim, is the speaker quickly states he is talking about Anatolia, which is not the whole of Turkey.

Comment: @WeatherVane: AFAICT Anatolia has even fewer Kurds today than Turkey in general, so the claim would be even more surprising if (it were true when) restricted to that area.

Comment: The speaker also brings the point to "Erdoğan's dream of an Islamic state" which makes the claim even more like political cant.

Comment: Is there any official data in Turkey on who is or isn't of Kurdish ethnicity or is this solely by self-identification?